# Error "no Route matched with those values" in Kubernetes Ingress Controller

Tags: kubernetes-ingress

I have a kubernetes service deployed successfully. On top of it I have created a k8s ingress controller which is mapping to the deployed service on port 80 and path is just with front-slash ( / ). e.g. hostname of ingress is kubernetes-app.local and url is http://kubernetes-app.local:80 or http://kubernetes-app.local. However, suddenly after 2 days I am not able to get success response for the same url. There is nothing changed in ingress and service and also I can see that ingress and service are running successfully.
Not sure what happened and suddenly I started getting error as "no Route matched with those values". I redeployed the app but still facing the same. issue.
Any leads will be helpful.

Below is the information for your reference

$ kubectl version

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.4", GitCommit:"SOME_STRING", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-11-17T15:48:33Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.10", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.5+k3s2", GitCommit:"SOME_STRING", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-10-05T19:59:14Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

### service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service # Specify the type of manifest this is.  In this case a service, which is used to allow network access to pods.

metadata:
  labels:
    app: kubernetes-app-service
  name: kubernetes-app-service
  namespace: my-app-plus # Specify the name of the namespace to run this object under.

spec:
  type: ClusterIP # Type of Service.  Options are ClusterIP or NodePort
  clusterIP: None  # Specify an IP for the service.  None means K8S will auto assign an IP.

  selector:
    app: kubernetes-app-pod # Traffic to this service will be routed to pod(s) with this label.

  sessionAffinity: None

  ports:
    - name: default
      port: 80 # Port the service will be listening on
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 80 # Port that pod(s) will be listening on
```

### deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment  # Specify the type of manifest this is.  In this case a deployment, which is used to get and keep pods running.

metadata:
  labels:
    app: kubernetes-app
  name: kubernetes-app
  namespace: my-app-plus  # Specify the name of the namespace to run this object under.

spec:
  replicas: 1 # Specify how many copies of the pods we want running.
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kubernetes-app-pod  # Pods matching this label are part of this deployment

  strategy:  # Specify the rules for updating or replacing pods.
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%

  template:  # Here is where we will define the pods that the deployment will use.
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kubernetes-app-pod  # Set the label of the pod.  This is what the deployment selector up above is referencing. Services will also reference this.
      annotations:
        dapr.io/enabled: "true"
        dapr.io/app-id: "kubernetes-app"
        dapr.io/app-port: "80"
        dapr.io/config: "tracing"
    spec:      
      containers:  # Specify how the container(s) in this pod are created. 
        - name: kubernetes-app          
          image: ghcr.io/myuseridORorgName/app:1.1.0 # Docker image to create the container from.
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "256Mi"
              cpu: "250m"
            limits:
              memory: "1000Mi"
              cpu: "1000m"
          volumeMounts:
            - name: kubernetes-app-git-volume
              mountPath: /root/.gitconfig  # Creating the .gitconfig from the configmap we created earlier
              subPath: .gitconfig
          env:
            - name: dev
              value: "true"
          envFrom:
          - configMapRef:
              name: kubernetes-app-configmap
          - secretRef:
              name: kubernetes-app-secret
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: mysecrethub        
      volumes:
        - name: kubernetes-app-git-volume
          configMap:
            name: gitconfig
```

### ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress

metadata:
  name: kubernetes-app-ingress
  namespace: my-app-plus # Specify the name of the namespace to run this object under.

spec:
  rules:
    - host: kubernetes-app.local  # Traffic arriving at the load balancer to this Domain Name will get routed according to this ingress spec.
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: kubernetes-app-service # Traffic will be sent to a service with this label.
                port:
                  number: 80  # Port on the service to route traffic to.
```

Comment: Please update your question with more details: how did you install kubernetes? What is used? (like minikube or docker desktop with k8s enabled or microk8s, etc.). Logs/events from your cluster? Where exactly you see this error? Ingress manifest and `kubectl describe` output. So it should be more details provided so community can try to help you.

Comment: Manifests look well + they worked before. So the issue with underlying something. How did you install your kubernetes cluster? Please provide more details so it can be possible to reproduce the environment. Where exactly do you see this error? You can also try to expose your service with `NodePort` or `LoadBalancer` type to see if the app actually works.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was due to same port (80) was used by other ingresses. Just run below command which will show you other ingresses with same port and ip

$kubectl get ingress

```
ingress-1  IP-1 80
ingress-2  IP-1 80
ingress-3  IP-1 80
```

So I just deleted ingress-2 and 3 which we don't use, and it worked.
If this does not work for you, simply delete everything from your namespace along with all ingresses and redeploy your application, it will definitely work.